# Intersection area of all n rectangles

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, area

I have no idea how to begin this, preferably providing me with an algorithm to help.  The question goes as follows, for `n` rectangles, an input is called to define each rectangle.  Limits of `n` is `1000`, while limits of the coordinates are `10000`.

4 numbers are given,

```
x1, x2, y1, y2
```

such that the rectangle is bounded by

```
x=x1, x=x2, y=y1, y=y2
```

The problem arises when I am required to find the intersecting area between all these rectangles.  Any idea how the algorithm should work?

My idea:  I implement a loop that creates the coordinates bounding the intersected square the first time.  Then for each new loop, I check if the next inputted coordinates intersect.

Comment: How would you do this on a piece paper? Is there a property that you notice for the intersection's coordinates(or shape)?

Comment: Is there any constraints? Maximum number of `n`?

Comment: @PhamTrung the constraint is 1000

Comment: Yes, and what traversing systematic would you use, if you couldn't write on Ivaylos paper, but only take notes on a second sheet to write down one number per two rects.

Comment: Could you just add it into the question? How about `x` and `y`?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I would compare the 2 lower corners with the 2 upper corners of the other rectangle.

Comment: @XcoderX this is a for a single rectangle. But how to handle the intersection of many rectangles? Are there any properties you could use?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not aware, thats why I asked. @IvayloStrandjev could you tell me?

Comment: This was a challenge on [/r/dailyprogrammer](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer) a while back.

Comment: So once you've got the overlap of 2 rectangles, is there any way that you could use the result to get the result with 3 rectangles?

Comment: Do you know sweep line algorithm?

Comment: No, not really.  Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: I am sorry, that does not answer the question.  My question is to find the common/interssecting area of every rectangle

Comment: Wait, this question is to find the area that contained by `all` rectangles? So this is much easier.

Comment: yes.  for instance, 0202, 0303, and 100,1000,100,1000 will return 0, @PhamTrung

Comment: To expand on @UKMonkey 's hint: If the result of intersecting 2 rectangles is a rectangle, what happens if you intersect that result with a third rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to find 4 items: the maximum value of the left position and the top position, and the minimum value of the right position and the bottom position. (Assuming the positive axis of X and Y point to right and down, as is often the case in CS)

So the minimal code could be:

```
int lv = -1, tv = -1, rv = 10001, bv = 10001;
int l, t, r, b;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // cin >> l >> t >> r >> b; Input
    lv = max(lv, l);
    tv = max(tv, t);
    rv = min(rv, r);
    bv = min(bv, b);
}
```

Then you know if `lv <= rv && tv <= bv`, there's an intersection specified by those 4 values. If `lv > rv || tv > bv`, there's no common intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Set intersection rectangle to the first rectangle, then find intersection with the second rectangle and update intersection, then repeat for all rectangles left.

In pseudocode:

```
std::vector<Rect> rects;
Rect intersection = rects[0];
for( int i = 1; i < rects.size(); ++i)
{
    intersection = getIntersection( intersection, rect[i] );
}
```

Comment: The `intersection` could be multiple rectangles.

Comment: @PhamTrung in question "intersecting area between all these rectangles" not all intersecting areas.